# create custom SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I created a custom SimpleCursorAdapter, because i want a text and 2 buttons per row.

If i click on a button, he should call the Activity Lektion.
In this Lektion he should know from which Button the call came, so i thought about sending the id of the Lektion as a Bundle in the onClickEvent.

But this doesnt work, it just saves me always the last id..

How can i do this?

```
public class LektionenCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{
    private Cursor c;
    private Context context;
    private Bundle bundle;

    public LektionenCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        this.c = c;
        this.context = context;
    }


    public View getView(int pos, View inView, ViewGroup parent){
       if(inView == null){
           inView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.lektionenoverview_entry, null);
       }
       View row = inView;

       this.c.moveToPosition(pos);

       String id = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
       Log.i("Cursor", id);
       String description = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex("Description"));
       String info = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex("Info"));
       String test = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex("Test"));

       TextView descriptionTextView = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.description);
       Button infoButton = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.infoButton);
       Button testButton = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.testButton);

       bundle = new Bundle();
       bundle.putString("LektionNummer", id);

       descriptionTextView.setText(id+". "+description);

       if(info != null && info.length() > 0){          
            infoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Lektion.class);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                context.startActivity(intent);                  
            }
        });

       }
       if(test != null && test.length() > 0){

       }
       return row;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a CursorAdapter because you want to show 2 lines and button, you can use any other simpler adapter.

getView method is called multiple times for each view, not when you click on the view or button. You are re-instantiating the Bundle everytime and it is just saving the id for the last getView call (because every call destroys the previous one), and you are also creating a new OnClickListener on every call.

You probably want to use OnItemClickListener and create only one instance outside getView() method.

Comment: but i dont want to click on the whole row.

i have many rows, with always 2 buttons, how can i differ between these buttons? because for example infoButton1 calls Lektion1 and infoButton2 calls Lektion2, it should know which button i clicked because of the row..

Comment: my mistake about OnItemClick. The fastest way to make your code working is to stop recreating the Bundle on every getView. Maybe you could use setTag method to add store the id. The main problem is you are creating a new Bundle on every call, and thus deleting the previous one (that's why you only can get the latest row working)